# Error message: impossible to buy the item

Tags: google-play, in-app-purchase

I'm working on an app that has inapp purchase.

When I'm in test mode, I can "buy" the item and everything works fine. But when I use a real account to test the purchase in real mode, then I have this error message: "unable to buy the item". I don't understand why this is happening...

I'm really stuck and need some help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Sign out of the current gmail account associated with the current play store. Then Clear play stores app data. after that, Reset your phone. restore factory data. Remember to unroot ur device before resetting as the root program will return everything back to how it was. Making the reset pointless. also backup ur data. Then reset factory data. After that. Sign in with a totally New gmail account. And download the apps and make your purchases. Then root ur phone again if you please. I'm going to try this and see if it works.

Comment: Hello, i reset the phone from factory settings - I don't know what you mean by "root the phone". In my case, the phone is a test device so I have nothing in it, I can reset it over and over again, it doesn't matter. So I reset it and downloaded the app again, tested and still have the error... Did you try on your side ?

Comment: any help ? did anybody face this issue ?